# Como criar uma expressão regular

Tags: php, html, string, regex

Tenho a seguinte div com informações

```html
<div class="endereco-item">
 <h2 class="azulclaro identify">Casa</h2>
 <div class="entrelinha_0"></div>
 <div class="font_15"></div>
 <div class="font_15"></div>
 <div class="font_15">R: Antonio Pires dos Santos, 647   praça central</div>
 <div class="font_15">Parque santo antonio - Sao Paulo - SP</div>
 <div class="font_15">CEP: 55555-555</div>
 <div class="font_15">Fone: (11)943-056-295 (55)555-555-555</div>
 <div id="ctl00_Body_rptEnderecos_ctl00_dvRadio" class="font_15 custom-checkbox">
 <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="radioSelect" checked onclick="setPrincipal(0)" />
```

qual seria a expressão regular para pegar a cidade São paulo e o estado SP ?

Comment: Eu creio que você está querendo resolver um problema com uma ferramenta não adequada a esse problema. Por que você pensou em expressões regulares?

Comment: É que já tentei de outras maneiras e não tive sucesso, preciso botar esse texto em variáveis para criar um array.

Comment: O recomendado é a utilização de um DOM parsing para web scrapping, depois, caso seja necessário o RegEx para realizar ajustes finos. Mas tente esta expressão: `[\s\w]+?-\s*[A-Z]{2}(?=<\/div>)` e o [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sCveyL/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o formato for sempre esse apresentado na pergunta, "bairro - cidade - estado", sendo que o estado é representado por duas letras maiúsculas, fica até tranquilo:

```
>.* - (.*) - ([A-Z]{2})<
```

(Segue exemplo da expressão regex101: https://regex101.com/r/EPTpOM/1)

Ou seja, um fechameto de tag `>`, seguido de qualquer sequência de caracteres (bairro), seguida do separador " - ", seguida de qualquer sequência de caracteres que queremos guardar no *rematch* (cidade), outro separador, outro *rematch* para um par te letras maiúsculas (estado) e, por último, uma abertura de tag `<`.

No caso do PHP você pode passar um array para a função [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Assim, a cidade e estados serão retornados nos elementos 1 e 2 do array, respectivamente:

```
<?php
$html='<div class="endereco-item">
    <h2 class="azulclaro identify">Casa</h2>
    <div class="entrelinha_0"></div>
    <div class="font_15"></div>
    <div class="font_15"></div>
    <div class="font_15">R: Antonio Pires dos Santos, 647   praça central</div>
    <div class="font_15">Parque santo antonio - Sao Paulo - SP</div>
    <div class="font_15">CEP: 55555-555</div>
    <div class="font_15">Fone: (11)943-056-295 (55)555-555-555</div>
    <div id="ctl00_Body_rptEnderecos_ctl00_dvRadio" class="font_15 custom-checkbox">
    <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="radioSelect" checked onclick="setPrincipal(0)" />';

$cidade_estado = array();
$regex = '/>.* - (.*) - ([A-Z]{2})</';
preg_match($regex, $html, $cidade_estado);

print_r($cidade_estado);
```

(Segue exemplo do código PHP no repl.it: https://repl.it/NvhF/0)

Comment: Pode ser purismo de minha parte, mas eu detesto usar expressões regulares para extrair informação de um pedaço de texto regido por uma gramática livre se contexto

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado concordo que ele poderia explodir a string no `\n`, pegar a quinta linha, eliminar o HTML e aí sim ter um contexto mais "puro" para aplicar uma expressão regular (que aí seria até desnecessária)... Ainda assim (pode me queimar na fogueira por heresia) costumo usar bastante expressão regular em *web scraping*, então rolou uma identificação pessoal com o problema apresentado, haha...

Comment: Seu herege! Morra queimado! Hahaha! Sem brincadeira, eu abuso das pobres e inocentes expressões regulares para trabalhos porcos e rápidos. Muitas vezes eu acabo por usar `sed`s e `grep`s em sequência. Poderia usar uma vez ou outra na vida para identificar conteúdo em códigos fonte ou HTML, mas não faço isso, digamos, a nível de por em produção. A minha última jornada nisso foi automatizar uma substituição de texto em Java para pegar um _singleton_ de classes cujos nomes terminavam em `async`, no lugar de instanciar esses objetos novamente

Comment: Sou obrigado a usar um comentário pra linkar esse [blog post um tanto antigo do XKCD](https://blog.xkcd.com/2009/04/27/a-problem/comment-page-2/)... 3 regex em `perl` e 2 `grep`, sendo um deles variável e recursivo dentro de um `xargs`. A gente sempre acha absurdos maiores por aí, haha...

Comment: Gente! Como que eu nunca tinha descido no blog? Só tinha ficado nas tirinhas e no _What if_... Hahahaha! Muito bom!

Answer (score 2):

É um tanto quanto complicado pegar a Cidade e Estado nesse seu html.

Fiz um teste aqui e consegui utilizando a seguinte Expressão Regular:

`/(?![^<>]*>)-\s?(?P<cidade>[a-zA-z].*?)\s?-\s?(?P<estado>[a-zA-Z]{2})/`

Dessa forma ele encontra a cidade e estado mesmo se tiver variáveis em espaços, e na digitação. Fiz uma bagunça no código para teste e mesmo assim ele conseguiu pegar de várias formas diferentes.

Segue o teste com o código bagunçado, onde coloquei cidades e estados em várias partes do código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas se você puder alterar o html sugiro colocar **ID**s em cada `div`. Assim facilitaria bastante utilizar uma expressão regular que buscasse direto pela div certa.

Mas espero que essa expressão que criei dê certo para você.